# Как растянуть изображение по ширине экрана или другой вариант вывода сообщения об ошибке на Django

Tags: django, img, sendmessage

Пишу сайт на Django. По дизайну сообщение должно выводиться перед всеми объектами на странице:
[image: Пример реализации]

Но я пока не понимаю как это сделать. Сейчас реализовано через тэг `dialog`

html-файл

```
{% if messages %}
<dialog class="error" open="open" id="closeMe" style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
    <form method="dialog" class="error">
        <button class="error">
            <img src="{% static '/img/Ошибки входа.png' %}" style="object-fit: fill ">
        </button>
    </form>
</dialog>
{% endif %}
```

css-файл

```
.error, form>.error>img {
    border: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #ffffff00;
}
```

Но пока выходит вот так, т.е. где огромное пространство, там находится участок кода с `dialog`. Если вы знаете как вывести подобное сообщение поверх страницы, прошу подсказать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден методом тыка. В Css поменять значение у `position` и добавить фиксацию ко всем краям кроме нижнего.

`css-файл` у `.error, form>.error>img`

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
```